# Which solution to use for loading HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am providing my site users capability to do real-time chat. Currently to start the chat users click on a click-able icon in the site, and once clicked, it should bring up a slide-up, or whatever, but not a new pop-up window, to load a plain HTML page which uses pusher.com's real-time chat code.

I tried using Fancybox, but I couldn't get an external HTML code to load.

I really want something simple, and don't wanna over-engineer anything.

What solution would you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=fancybox+url first hit

Comment: Yes, I have studied that link and I evaluated FancyBox for 2 days. It doesn't work. Anyhow thanks. Just tried Colorbox, and it works after 5 mins of copy-n-pasting.

Comment: it works fine on the demo page...